# tum simulator cloning problem

Tags: ros, simulation, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working in the proxy network of my college. And i did all proxy setting in my system whatever i know. but when i executing following command, it return following error:

```
root@chhonkar-pc:~# git clone https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator.git
Cloning into 'tum_simulator'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

system : ubuntu 14.04
ros : indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197446/tum-simulator-cloning-problem/) by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're having trouble accessing that url via a proxy I think you still need to work on your proxy settings.

I have confirmed that your command works fine for me.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-11-16**:
I done cloning but next problem arises, I unable to launch any .launch file as mentioned in section 3.2 in following link:
*http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator*

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-11-16**:
Open a new question with a detailed description of what doesn't work. Also, try going through the basic ROS tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials